# Normalize volume of MPEG-4 AAC tunes purchased from iTunes?

Tags: music, mp3, music-player, replaygain

I've been very satistied using a combination of Picard and QuodLibet to calcuate Replay Gain tag values for me MP3s.  Anyone know how to do this with AAC songs?

Edit:  I usually use Rhythmbox and QuodLibet for listening.

Comment: What are you using to listening?

Comment: [easymp3gain-gtk](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/easymp3gain-gtk/) claims to do this and has a dependency for mp3gain but not for [aacgain](http://aacgain.altosdesign.com/) which was only available in the Medibuntu repositories which are now gone as well as the Debian one. Either mp3gain has been patched can do this now or this functionality is broken. The neroaac blobs are poorly documented and don't seem to have this functionality.

Comment: Note that aacgain (and mp3gain) do not actually work by writing the RG tags - they physically modify the frame volume throughout the song, having _analysed_ with the RG algorithms.

Note also: although more reliable to actually adjust the volume across all sorts of players, it is technically destructive (albeit undoable) and write-heavy (i.e. slower / backup unfriendly) for larger volumes of processing.

Answer (score 0):

What wasn't working for you?

Having just tried this out, I *can* do this in (current) Quod Libet on an AAC (`.m4a`) album, using the [Replay Gain Plugin](http://quodlibet.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/playback/replaygain.html), and confirming the RG tags look OK and sound about right when enabling / disabling the RG on playback (as it happens I wrote some of that code too). They are marked as read-only though, but this doesn't bother me.